# date-fns parse for "/Date(1633421520000)/"

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-fns

receiving string of date that looks like this `"/Date(1633421520000)/"`,

with moment I could just use it as `moment("/Date(1633421520000)/")` **whats the equivalent for date-fns** ?

for example `differenceInMilliseconds` how would i use it with received argument as this string `"/Date(1633421520000)/"`

not sure how to create my date object from this string so ill be able to use date-fns functions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the number (which looks like milliseconds since unix epoch) from the string:

```
"/Date(1634717139973)/".match(/\d+/)[0]
```

Then use `Date` constructor like so:

```
var date = new Date(Number("/Date(1634717139973)/".match(/\d+/)[0]));
date.toISOString(); // 2021-10-20T08:05:39.973Z
```

Comment: moment works just fine like this `moment("/Date(1633421520000)/")`, the question whats the equivalent to use this format with date-fns ?

Comment: `new Date(Number("1634717139973"))` will give you a JavaScript date object, if that is what you're after.

Comment: The problem with using *match* is that if there is no match, you'll get an error whereas if you use something like *replace*, e.g. `new Date(Number("/Date(1634717139973)/".replace(/\D/g,''))).toISOString()` which always returns a Date object and won't throw errors if given say "/Date" (i.e. there are no digits). You just have to test if the returned Date is valid or not (e.g. `if (isNaN(dateObj)) ...`). :-)